# Cannot resolve symbol android

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

I am very new to Android studio and following some tutorials on YouTube.

My program was working fine. But, suddenly it showed `android` in red.

> Cannot resolve symbol android.

I was working on creating a list and the problematic line is:

> ArrayAdapter(this.android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,favouriteMovies);

Here is my code:

```java
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            String[]favouriteMovies = { "The Pursuit Of Happiness","Hangover","Jannat","3 Idiots","Lagaan",
            "The Social Network","A lot like love"};
            ListAdapter TheAdapter = new
            ArrayAdapter<String>(this.**android**.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,favouriteMovies); 
            ListView Thelist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Thelist);
            Thelist.setAdapter(TheAdapter);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo:

Change

```
ArrayAdapter(this.android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,favouriteMovies);
```

with

```
ArrayAdapter(this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,favouriteMovies);
```

[Check the doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) to see the parameters accepted by the constructors.